# The date time format will be auto converted by YAML.load from 2.0

Tags: ruby, yaml

I am upgrading ruby to 2.2 from 1.8 for my production.
In the ruby 1.8, I will get the result as I expected.
But in ruby 2.2, the result is very strange, anyone knows how to fix it.

```
YAML.load("start_time: 2012-09-24T13:00:00")
```

In ruby 1.8, `{"start_time"=>"2012-09-24T13:00:00"}`

In ruby 2.2, `{"start_time"=>2012-09-24 23:00:00 +1000}`

Comment: I didn't see any difference.

Comment: the result in ruby 1.8 : {"start_time"=>"2012-09-24T13:00:00"}

Answer (score 1):

You can enclose the time within single quotes, the YAML parser will treat the time as a string.

```
YAML.load("start_time: '2012-09-24T13:00:00'")
=> {"start_time"=>"2012-09-24T13:00:00"}
```